# Angular AOT changes component file name adding .ngfactory creating url reference errors on include

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-aot

So AOT changes the name of my components, for example `my-component.component.ts` to `my-component.component.ngfactory.ts` but then on the generated file includes the file doing so

`import * as import2 from './my-component.component';`

which is wrong cause this file is not there anymore.

If I change the import on the file to be like

`import * as import2 from './contact-us.component.ngfactory';`

then I can see how for example my IDE stops complaining cause this file does exists.

Does someone now how to make the AOT compiler either not modify the file names or modify the import accordingly? LEt me know if you need to see any config file

This is how my tsconfig looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist/out-tsc"
  },

  "files": [
    "app/app.module.ts",
    "main-aot.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "../aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

And the received error is

```
Error at C:/Projects/my-project/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts:74:27: Cannot find module './components/my-component.component'.
```